# Найти регулярное выражение python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Необходимо написать регулярное выражение python, которое убирает username пользователей, каналов, ботов в телеграм.
В username используются символы `a-z`, `0-9`, `_`. Его длина от 5 до 32 символов.

Строка ввода:

> Кому нужен контакт, в телеграме ник @ex4mpl3 Вссем удачи))

Строка вывода:

> Кому нужен контакт, в телеграме ник  Вссем удачи))

Строка ввода:

> @nachalo_stroki - продаю юзернейм

Строка вывода:

> - продаю юзернейм

Вот мой код. Но неправильно обрабатывает, если `@nachalo_stroki`. Как это исправить?

```py
import re
s=input()
pat = r'[^|\\+-@a-z0-9_][@a-z0-9_]{5,32}\b'
rep = " "
p = re.sub(pat,rep,s)
print(p)
```

Comment: Почему у вас ник заменяется на пробел? Может быть лучше заменять на пустую строку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код:

```
import re
s=input()
pat = r'@[a-z0-9_]{5,32}\b'
rep = ""
p = re.sub(pat,rep,s)
print(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

Условию имени пользователей, каналов, ботов в телеграмм удовлетворяет такое регулярное выражение:

```
@[a-z0-9_]{5,32}
```

Comment: @[a-z0-9_]{5,32}\b

Comment: @ВасилийКалеев я правда не понял, чем Вас не устроил флаг Multiline